# Apache HttpComponents BasicHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I recently switched from `java.net` to `org.apache.http.client`, I have setup a `ClosableHttpClient` with the `HttpClientBuilder`. As connection manager I am using the `BasicHttpClientConnectionManager`.

Now I have the problem that very often when I create some HTTP request I get a timeout exception. It seems that the connection manager is keeping connections open to reuse them but if the system is idle for a few minutes then this connection will timeout and when I make the next request the first thing I get is a timeout. Repeating the same request one more time then usually works without any problem.

Is there a way to configure the `BasicHttpClientConnectionManager` in order to not reuse its connections and create a new connection each time?

Comment: @ScaryWombat looking at the documentation of java.net.Socket it seems that the socket timeout will only control how long the `read()` call will block. Are you sure thats suitable in my situation? `closeIdleConnections` it seem will only close **currently** idle connections and will only have an effect one time. But I need something that i can configure once and it will apply for all opened connections.

Comment: sorry you are right

Comment: @ScaryWombat ok, thanks anyway, do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There several ways of dealing with the problem

1. Evict idle connections once no longer needed. The code below effectively disables connection persistence by closing out persistent connections after each HTTP exchange.

   ```
   BasicHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager();
   CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm).build();
   ...
   try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("/"))) {
       System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
       EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
   }
   cm.closeIdleConnections(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   ```
2. Limit connection keep-alive time to something relatively small-ish

   ```
   BasicHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager();
   CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
           .setConnectionManager(cm)
           .setKeepAliveStrategy((response, context) -> 1000)
           .build();
   try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("/"))) {
       System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
       EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
   }
   ```
3. **(Recommended)** Use pooling connection manager and set connection total time to live to a finite value. There are no benefits to using the basic connection manager compared to the pooling one unless your code is expected to run in an EJB container.

   ```
   CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
           .setConnectionTimeToLive(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .build();
   try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("/"))) {
       System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
       EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
   }
   ```